# Ubuntu Phone display defect

Tags: ubuntu-touch, display, phone

When accessing my Ubuntu phone, I a regularly asked to enter my device PIN. Now, while this PIN contains a "0", BUT I cannot activate any key of the bottom row, I cannot enter my phone any more.

I am a bit irritated whether this a hardware or a software bug. "Pressing" any key of the row above works perfectly. On the other hand, whiping things from bottom to top is almost non-working. So my assumption is that this is more a hardware bug.

Has anybody some idea:
- Do you know this problem?
- Do you know whether it's a hardware or a software bug?
- Do you know what to do best?

I hope that I don't have to change the display once more, as getting the current one was quite a effort (the display being shipped from China).

Comment: That definitely sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: one possibility if there is a screen protector on the phone. bubbles under the screen protector will interfere with touch sensing at the same level as the bubble

Comment: Thanks! No, there is no screen protector. This one is already a replacement display, as I broke the original one... the replacement is not so easy to purchase. The first shipment from China got lost. The second one brought this display, which had some flickering issues. So I fear I'm going to buy another phone, maybe the Shift Phone.